# Javascript Cannot read property 'rows' of null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move table rows up and down and found a nice little tutorial that I am trying to get to work.  My page will have up to 8 tables but I am currently trying to get this to work with 1.  The only difference here is that rather than using the 'table' element I have given my table an id='cn' (this is to differenciate them once I can get 1 to work).  I have changed the id to be 'table' and still get this error.  What am I doing wrong? The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null"

```
var index;
function getSelectedRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("cn");
    for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick=function(){
           // clear the selected from the previous selected row
           // the first time index is undefined
           if(typeof index !== "undefined"){
              table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
           }

           index=this.rowIndex;
           this.classList.toggle("selected");
        };

    }

} getSelectedRow();
function upNdown(direction) {
    var rows = document.getElementById("cn").rows,
        parent = rows[index].parentNode;

    if (direction === "up") {
        if (index>1) {
            parent.insertBefore(rows[index], rows[index-1]);
           // when the row goes up the index will be equal to index -1
           index--;
        }
    }
    if (direction === "down") {
        if (index<rows.length-1) {
            parent.insertBefore(rows[index+1], rows[index]);
           // when the row goes up the index will be equal to index -1
           index++;
        }
    }

}
```

```
<table class='tbl1' style='margin-bottom:10px;' id='<?php echo getroute($row['route']);?>'>

      <caption><?php echo $row['route'];?>  
         <button onclick='upNdown("up");'> <b>&#8593;</b></button>
         <button onclick='upNdown("down");'> <b>&darr;</b> </button>
      </caption>
         <tr><th>Stop</th>
             <th>Invoice</th>
             <th>Client</th>
             <th>Destination</th>
             <th>C / B</th>
             <!-- <th></th> -->
             <th>Del Inst.</th></tr>
```

```
<button onclick='upNdown("up","<?php echo getroute($row['route']);?>");'> <b>&#8593;</b></button>
         <button onclick='upNdown("down","<?php echo getroute($row['route']);?>");'> <b>&darr;</b> </button>
```

The table rows are listed here.

Comment: SHouldnt you use `document.getElementById("<?php echo getroute($row['route']);?>").rows` ?

Comment: also you should be calling this after DOM is loaded, or on the end of the html: `getSelectedRow();`

Comment: Obviously this means that `document.getElementById("cn");` returns `null` at the point of execution. That either means that an element with `id="cn"` does not, or not yet, exist.

Comment: What is the *actual* value of the table ID in the output HTML?

Comment: Ariel, I haven't gotten to that part yet.  Currently I need it to work statically before I work on dynamically.  Update: I moved the script to the bottom of the page and it was moving the rows.  THis is now working.  Any ideas where to call the function from different tables?

Comment: I am trying to pass the table id throught he button but that gave me "Uncaught ReferenceError: tbl is not defined at getSelectedRow".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you have changed the id on the table to "cn"

```
<table class='tbl1' style='margin-bottom:10px;' id='<?php echo getroute($row['route']);?>'>
```

should be

```
<table class='tbl1' style='margin-bottom:10px;' id='cn'>
```

this should allow you to test out the functionality before you implement dynamic id's

Comment: The php gives each table a unique id based on data from the db.  Currently I have 3 tables with id's of 'cn', 'cs', and 'sw'. But can have up to 8.